# KeyError: 'love'. Please help me find a solution

Tags: python, nlp

```
def sentence_to_avg(sentence, word_to_vec_map):
    # Get a valid word contained in the word_to_vec_map. 
    any_word = list(word_to_vec_map.keys())[0]
    
    ### START CODE HERE ###
    # Step 1: Split sentence into list of lower case words (≈ 1 line)
    words = (sentence.lower()).split()

    # Initialize the average word vector, should have the same shape as your word vectors.
    avg = np.zeros((word_to_vec_map[words[0]].shape))
    
    # Initialize count to 0
    count = 0
    
    # Step 2: average the word vectors. You can loop over the words in the list "words".
    for w in words:
        # Check that word exists in word_to_vec_map
        if w in word_to_vec_map:
            avg += word_to_vec_map[w]
            # Increment count
            count +=1
          
    if count > 0:
        # Get the average. But only if count > 0
        avg = avg / len(words)
    
    ### END CODE HERE ###
    
    return avg
```

The following code gives error: KeyError: 'love'. Please help me identify the issue.
I have tried various combinations but none have worked

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Comment: Also, please add the code where you're calling the function (with sample inputs).

Comment: avg = sentence_to_avg("Morrocan couscous is my favorite dish", word_to_vec_map)
print("avg = \n", avg)

Comment: <ipython-input-29-c5f83fd9bfae> in sentence_to_avg(sentence, word_to_vec_map)
     22 
     23     # Initialize the average word vector, should have the same shape as your word vectors.
---> 24     avg = np.zeros((word_to_vec_map[words[0]].shape))
     25 
     26     # Initialize count to 0

KeyError: 'love'

Comment: Please update your question with all these details, plus the contents of `word_to_vec_map`. We need to be able to run your code.

Comment: word_to_vec_map = {'a': [3, 3], 'synonym_of_a': [3, 3], 'a_nw': [2, 4], 'a_s': [3, 2], 
                       'c': [-2, 1], 'c_n': [-2, 2],'c_ne': [-1, 2], 'c_e': [-1, 1], 'c_se': [-1, 0], 
                       'c_s': [-2, 0], 'c_sw': [-3, 0], 'c_w': [-3, 1], 'c_nw': [-3, 2]
                      }

Comment: for key in word_to_vec_map.keys():
        word_to_vec_map[key] = np.array(word_to_vec_map[key])
        
    avg = target("a a_nw c_w a_s", word_to_vec_map)

    assert np.allclose(avg, [1.25, 2.5]),  "Check that you are finding the 4 words"
    avg = target("love a a_nw c_w a_s", word_to_vec_map)
    assert np.allclose(avg, [1.25, 2.5]), "Divide between count not len(words)"
    avg = target("love", word_to_vec_map)
    assert np.allclose(avg, [0, 0]), "Average of no words must give an array of zeros"
    avg = target("c_se foo a a_nw c_w a_s deeplearning c_nw", word_to_vec_map)

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67809217/edit) your question with these details.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this line instead

```
avg = np.zeros(word_to_vec_map[any_word].shape)
```

and

```
if count > 0:
    # Get the average. But only if count > 0
    avg = avg / count
```

Answer (score 0):

For Initialize the average word vector, use

```
avg = np.zeros(word_to_vec_map[any_word].shape[0])
```

and if count is greater than 0, you'd want to divide by count -->

```
if count > 0:
     # Get the average.
     avg = avg / count
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope that could help someone else
note that the key solution is

> ```
> avg = np.zeros(word_to_vec_map[any_word[0]].shape)
> ```

```
def sentence_to_avg(sentence, word_to_vec_map):
    
    # Get a valid word contained in the word_to_vec_map. 
    any_word = list(word_to_vec_map.keys())[0]
    
    ### START CODE HERE ###
    # Step 1: Split sentence into list of lower case words (≈ 1 line)
    words = [word.lower() for word in sentence.split(' ') if word != '']

    # Initialize the average word vector, should have the same shape as your word vectors.
    # Use `np.zeros` and pass in the argument of any word's word 2 vec's shape
    avg = np.zeros(word_to_vec_map[any_word[0]].shape)
    
    # Initialize count to 0
    count = 0
    
    # Step 2: average the word vectors. You can loop over the words in the list "words".
    for w in words:
        # Check that word exists in word_to_vec_map
        if w in word_to_vec_map:
            avg += word_to_vec_map[w]
            # Increment count
            count +=1
          
    if count > 0:
        # Get the average. But only if count > 0
        avg = avg/count
    
    ### END CODE HERE ###
    
    return avg
```

Answer (score 0):

you should write this line in your code:

`avg = np.zeros(word_to_vec_map[any_word].shape)`

the 'any_word' is in the code for this purpose.